# webGL,SLGL? where should I start with this code

Tags: webgl

I am familiar with `C` or `C++`

However, I am a quite newbie for `WEBGL` and `GLSL`.

It might be too basic or silly question though... I appreciate you give me some hints.

---

I found this source code which makes the great CG graphics.

I want to compile this by myself, However honestly saying I am not sure what it is , and what with compiler I can compile and make this work .

```
#define R rotate2D
for(float i,e,g,s;i++<1e2;g+=e*.2)
{
    vec3 n,p=vec3((FC.xy-.5*r)/r.y*g,g-4.);
    p.zy*=R(.4);
    p.z+=t;
    e=p.y;
    for(s=1.;s<6e3;s+=s)p.xz*=R(s),n.xz*=R(s),n+=cos(p*s),e+=dot(sin(p.xz*s),r/r/s/3.);
    n.y=1.;
    n=normalize(n);
    e-=snoise2D(p.xz*40.)*n.y*n.y*.4;
    o-=exp(-e*9.-5.);
}
o++;
```

So at first, I started to learn about `webGL`.

And finished learning basic `webGL`

However I cant make it work with `webGL`.

Next, I started to learn about `SLGL` on unity,,, however it's not hit the spot.

What should I learn to compile this???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks a piece of a GLSL shader, and you would [compile that with `gl.compileShader()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebGLRenderingContext/compileShader)

But it's incomplete. First of all to be completely compilable it needs a `main` function that sets `gl_FragColor`. And I see a reference to `snoise2D` and `rotate2D` which should be functions, but are missing. And a least a few local undefined variables like `FC` and `r`. So without those pieces, this won't compile.

If you can solve those issues, you should be able to plug into something like [ShaderToy](https://www.shadertoy.com/) without have to invent a whole WebGL application from scratch. But if this shader is meant to interact with specific geometry that might not work at all.

It's hard to advise more without more info on what this is, how its intended and what all that single letter variable names are supposed to mean.

Comment: thank you to your clear advice. I am interested in Shader more. ShaterToy is  also interesting and good to start.  I need to start myself to archive goal.